# robot_pose_ekf coordinate frame

Tags: navigation, kinect, visual-odometry, coordinate-system, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a visual odometry source which outputs Ros odometry msg in a coordinate system of the camera which is z-axis forward. Now i also have an Imu based odometry which gives data according to coordinate frame of the world which is x-axis forward.
If i input these two sources in the robot_pose_ekf package, the pose published from the package would be according to which coordinate system?

If this could cause a problem should i convert the visual odometry to the world's coordinate system with x-axis forward terminology.? Also what about the related published tf..?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52820/robot_pose_ekf-coordinate-frame/) by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 263 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki page of robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) says that all poses are *robot poses*. So every source of information should publish pose information of the robot (and not the sensor). [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) could help you to understand odometry frames. If your odometry source publishes sensor movements you will have to transform this to robot movements.

Have a look at [viso2_ros::OdometerBase::integrateAndPublish()](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/viso2_ros/html/odometer__base_8h_source.html#l00099) for an example of how to transform sensor pose information to robot pose information using tf.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2013-01-23**:
So this means i should transform the visual odometry from z-axis forward frame to robot frame which is X-axis forward..?

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-01-23**:
Yes, the full transformation from your visual odometry frame to your robot base_link has to be used. Make sure all your motion input reports motion of the same frame (base_link).